# CodeIgniter / jQuery - Pagination - Endless Pagination

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Im trying to implement the endless pagination jquery plugin found here ( https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless ) into my codeigniter project.

The jquery code i enter is the same as whats on the demo page

```
$('#results').pageless({ totalPages: 10
, url: '/theurl/index'
, loaderMsg: 'Loading more results'
});
```

and the code i have in my codeigniter controller is as follows

```
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'theurl/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->model->record_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 20;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

    // Init the config
    $this->pagination->initialize( $config );

    // Create pagination
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data['results'] = $this->onyafeet->fetch_results($config['per_page'], $page);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    // Load the view and pass through all the data
    $this->load->view('theurl/index', $data);
```

When i run the code, and reach the bottom of the page, it does work, but it also loads the enter page into the new div it creates just for the results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You mean 'entire' page right? So what exactly is in your view that is being loaded, if it is the 'entire' page, that is what you will have nested upon a successful pagination call.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your response ... That makes total sense ... What would be the best way to get around this?

Comment: Create a view that contains only the data that needs to appear in your pagination results and call that instead.

Comment: So i would load that into the base_url of the config? ... im confused hahaha .. is there any chance of some example code?

Comment: Chococroc's answer below pretty much sums up my comments above... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you should load the results into a partial view, because otherwise you're loading again the whole page. Create a partial view to load all the data, and then, load the partial view into the main page:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'theurl/index';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->model->record_count();
$config['per_page'] = 20;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;

// Init the config
$this->pagination->initialize( $config );

// Create pagination
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data['results'] = $this->onyafeet->fetch_results($config['per_page'], $page);
$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
// AJAX load: 
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request) {
    $this->load->view('theurl/partial/ajax_partial',$data);
}
else {
    // Load the view and pass through all the data
    $this->load->view('theurl/index', $data);
}
```

I think that with this approach should work, the partial view must only have the right part that you want to show, the div with all the content you want to load asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for that .. it sort of works, except that now it loads the exact same results, also it wont work unless i loop through the results both on the partial and the non partial views :S

Comment: Mmm... Looking at the settings of 'pageless', I think your problem may be about the markup of your views: The MAIN view ('theurl/index') should have a markup element in which you'll charge next items. In 'pageless' I've seen you can specify this markup element and maybe setting: $('#results').pageless({ totalPages: 10
, url: '/theurl/index'
, loaderMsg: 'Loading more results', container: '#element'}); and adding <div id=element> BLABLA </div> in the MAIN page could works.